# What is the meaning of this lines spoken by Larry Talbot?

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Larry Talbot* says this words to her brother's wife:

> I seem to recall he mentioned you in one of his letters. And it's quite
>   uncharacteristic of my brother to treat a lady in such a way, but **the
>   character of man is such a shiftable thing**.

If Larry is taking about woman why does he mentions about **man** in this sentence: **character of man is such a shiftable thing**?

Comment: He's actually talking about the character of his ***brother*** (who has behaved uncharacteristically towards some particular lady), so the "gender mismatch" you're worried about doesn't exist here anyway. But in other contexts, ***the character of man*** could be seen a "genderless" term referring to the character of ***human beings in general*** (not just the males). English is less concerned with such gender distinctions than many other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is referring to the *character* of a man because

> I seem to recall **he** mentioned you in one of his letters. And it's quite uncharacteristic of **my brother** to treat a lady in such a way, but the character of man is such a shiftable thing.

He is talking about his brother.